# Anyone know of any (free / open source) VI integration for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, vim, add-in, vi

vi is for cool kids.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free vim add-in for Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141992/free-vim-add-in-for-visual-studio)

Comment: It is, but that other question was created after this one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/) - Not Free but great Vim emulation.
2. [Visual_Studio.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=864) - Allows you to manage visual studio from Vim.
3. [Using GVim as the Visual Studio Editor](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Calling_gvim_from_MS_Visual_Studio)

Comment: does visual_studio.vim give you intellisense?

Comment: No. The main thing it gives you is bidirectional jumps with the cursor in the right place, and a project file hierarchy. Unfortunately, it requires Python.

I think what we're ALL looking for is something that:

1. Opens vim inside VS as a sub-window
2. Supports omnicompletion via VS intellisense

Comment: If you add VsVim at the top, this answer would be best :)

Answer (score 55):

After @joe's answer, Jared Parsons created the great [VsVim](http://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim). It's been featured on [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329). It's a ready extension package. I downloaded it, ran the file and it worked out of the box. It's free, too.

Comment: It's still not entirely feature complete (for example, ci"/di" and other related commands, to change or delete within a given set of quotes/parens/etc are not implemented which drives me crazy).

Comment: After a number of months using this addin and monitoring a development progress i can say that author is committed to it a lot and you can use github to communicate with him and request a feature. Most probably it will be implemented surprisingly soon :

Answer (score 27):

Starting with Visual Studio 2010 you can use VsVim.  It's a free extension available on the extension gallery.  Source code is hosted on github

- http://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim
- http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329

Comment: Jared - you should add a link to the VsGallery page :)

Answer (score 6):

1. [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/) - Not Free but great Vim emulation.
2. [Visual_Studio.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=864) - Allows you to manage visual studio from Vim.
3. [Using GVim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Calling_gvim_from_MS_Visual_Studio) as the Visual Studio Editor

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Integrate_gvim_with_Visual_Studio

and  SO has  same details available in  [Anyone know of any (free / open source) VI integration for Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110477/anyone-know-of-any-free-open-source-vi-integration-for-visual-studio)

Comment: As i can see, only commercial viemu allows to edit code INSIDE visual studio with vim editing commands? Rest just allows to compile VS project from withing gvim?

Comment: You somply copied sontek's answer from that other question? Wow.

Answer (score 4):

ViEmu is not free but does what you want at a cost of $99.
You may also want to read this http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Integrate_gvim_with_Visual_Studio

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the gvim OLE package?  I have used it with previous versions of Visual Studio and it worked okay.

http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc -- gvim##ole.zip

A GUI version with OLE support. This offers a few extra features, such as integration with Visual Developer Studio. But it uses quite a bit more memory.