# Free vim add-in for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anyone know of any (free / open source) VI integration for Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110477/anyone-know-of-any-free-open-source-vi-integration-for-visual-studio)

Is it any free Visual Studio addons that emulate vim text edit mode? For now I have found only [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com), but it's $100.